# How to handle a BitmapImage when giving a image URI that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to download an image and set it as the source of a `BitmapImage`. But there's potentially a case where the image doesn't exist, i.e. the response is a 404. I'm currently doing this:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("link_to_image"));
```

Although there are no errors, I prefer to handle the case and show a message or something instead of just showing a blank `BitmapImage`. Is there a way to get the status code of the response? Or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the bitmapImage.[DownloadFiled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Reason for the failure can be read from  [ExceptionEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.exceptioneventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the event handler.